# Advanced plane 3d tracking and axis identification

Tags: camera, tracking

Are there any ways to make 3d tracking better?
Atm I have a problem with recreating room (example below). And as it can be seen red recrangle do not quite match walls, floor or ceiling. Quite nasty situation. I've tried to make 'floor' from points on the floor, on the walls, on the ceiling and even the blue screen. Nothing helps at all. Every time it kinda fits only one plane but as soon as I try to extend it to make a box these planes stop being parallel. So I'd like to know is there any way to mark meshes as walls, floor, ceiling apart from 2 default buttons since they do not work in my case.

Also is there any way to mark 2 trackers as x axis rather than just 1?  I mean if I've tracked 2 points on the floor and want to make 'em any axis can I?

[image: example]

Comment: Planar tracking will not give you 3d information. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332

Comment: To reconstruct space in 3D you need an image sequence that shows [parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax). Images from a single point of view or a static camera will not work for what you are trying to do.